# PowerShell command version

Tags: powershell

`Get-Command` returns version information, but that's not actually a version of the command, but a version from parent module. **Can I define a function with a different version than parent module?**

As per [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1#comment-based-help-keywords), there is no **version** defined as comment based help keyword.

Example:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Get-ADUser

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-ADUser                                         1.0.0.0    ActiveDirectory


PS C:\> Get-Command Get-ChildItem

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management


PS C:\> Get-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}


PS C:> Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management | Group-Object Version

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
   89 3.1.0.0                   {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
```

Comment: Functions don't have versions, cmdlets do. And then only the version of their parent modules. And then only modules that are not dynamic. If you really wanted this, you'd have to define a new module containing just the function, and load that to shadow the other module's definition... which seems like a lot of effort to go through just for one function.

Comment: It might just suffice to use `.Notes` for something like this. Depends on your audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Can I define a function with a different version than parent module?**

No.

---

EDIT:
As Jeroen Mostert told, you'd have to create an own module and define its version.